# Is it natural to ask "what color do you prefer to wear"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it natural to ask the following?

> What color clothes do you prefer to wear?

What I am trying to ask is clothes of what color the person prefers to wear.
 Whould it be more natural to ask

> what color clothes do you prefer to wear?

Or it would be more natural to ask

> what clothes colors do you prefer to wear?

Anyway, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: *What **color clothes** do you like?* is probably the most common form, but *What **clothes color / clothing color / color clothing...*** are all syntactically valid and wouldn't raise an eyebrow, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the two suggestions, the one that makes most sense grammatically is:

> What colour clothes do you prefer to wear?

This makes perfect sense and would be understood. That isn't to say it is particularly idiomatic, as I don't believe there isn't really any single, common way of asking this.

People do ask:

> What is your favourite colour?

This is a very broad question though, not necessarily to do with clothing. Children are more likely to ask this question, as the idea of having one single favourite colour for everything (clothes, home decor, flowers etc) is not held by most adults.

In fact, the reason why the question you are trying to ask is not all that common is probably that few people wear just one colour from head to toe.

It is idiomatic to refer to a single colour as "my colour", meaning that it is a colour which is complementary to one's looks, skin-tone etc. This would have to be used in context to make sense, for example:

> That jacket really suits you. Green is definitely your colour.

So, *in context* (ie you are already speaking about clothes) you could ask:

> What is your colour?